# I need when save picture type date and time now on it and save with date and time stamp from picture box visualbasic

Tags: vb.net

I need when save picture from picture box write date and time now on it picture itself and save with this stamp visualbasic

```
    Dim data As IDataObject
    Dim bmap As Image
    '  Dim g As Graphics = picCapture.CreateGraphics()
    ' g.DrawString("SAVED ON - " & Now, New Font("Arial", 18), Brushes.Yellow, 10, 10)

    ' Copy image to clipboard
    SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, 0, 0)

    ' Get image from clipboard and convert it to a bitmap

    data = Clipboard.GetDataObject()

    If data.GetDataPresent(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)) Then

        bmap = CType(data.GetData(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)), Image)

        picCapture.Image = bmap

        PictureBox1.Image = picCapture.Image


        sfdImage.FileName = TextBox1.Text

        SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")

        If sfdImage.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

            If InStr(sfdImage.FileName, ".bmp") Then

                bmap.Save(sfdImage.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

            Else
                bmap.Save(sfdImage.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

                'SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")
                TextBox1.Clear()
                TextBox1.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: What's different about this and the previous question you asked, where you got given the solution in the comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73804146/is-theres-any-way-to-add-time-and-date-on-picture-itself-when-save

Comment: Add it on main question

Comment: Please don't tag your question with both vb.net **and** vb6. They're different languages! Since you also added visual-studio, I assume it's vb.net so you should remove the vb6 tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can call graphics. FromImage to get the graphic object, and then call the draw string on that object to draw text on the image:
''''
Imports System

Private Sub Example_FromImage(ByVal hdc As IntPtr)
Dim graphics As New Graphics(hdc)

' Create an Image object from a PNG file.
Dim image As New Image("Mosaic.png")

' Create a Graphics object that is associated with the image.
Dim imageGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)

' Alter the image.
Dim brush As New SolidBrush(Color(255, 0, 0, 255))
imageGraphics.FillEllipse(brush, 10, 40, 100, 50)

' Draw the altered image.
graphics.DrawImage(image, 30, 20)

imageGraphics = Nothing
End Sub
'''''''
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-fromimage